# Vue: Why can't I use refs within component templates?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm struggling with Vue refs.  If I define them in my main Vue instance's template, they work fine, but if I define them within a component template, they don't.  What am I doing wrong?

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js, version 1**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    <div ref="divRef">
      <button ref="buttonRef">Submit</button>
    </div>
  `
});
```

**result (matches expectation)**

```
> app.$refs
> {buttonRef: button, divRef: div}
```

**main.js, version 2**

```js
Vue.component('demo-page', {
  template: `
    <div ref="divRef">
      <button ref="buttonRef">Submit</button>
    </div>
  `
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<demo-page ref="componentRef"></demo-page>'
});
```

**expected result**

```
> app.$refs
> {componentRef: VueComponent, buttonRef: button, divRef: div}
```

**actual result**

```
> app.$refs
> {componentRef: VueComponent}
```

Comment: Refs are scoped within a component. Try to access the refs within the scope of that component. Usually you don't need refs (only for the integration of e.g. chart libraries, especially not over the component boundaries). So, you could try to avoid using them at all and improve your architecture.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Ah, I see.  If you put that in an answer, I'll accept.  I was able to get my code working thanks to your comment.  I had a component containing a `v-for` directive to create a bunch of text-input elements.  The task at hand was to set the focus to a certain element in the component after adding or removing an element from the underlying array that component was bound to.  I had been trying to do that from the component's parent, but now I see that you can do it from the component itself: `this.$nextTick(() => {this.$refs.inputs[index].focus()});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$refs` are **scoped within a component**. That's the reason, you can only see the `componentRef` in the `$refs` of the app itself. The other `$refs` are accessible within the scope of each component. So, try to access the `$refs` within the scope of that component.

If you are defining a `ref` on an element also having the attribute **`v-for`** on it, `this.$refs.refName` will return you an array of DOM elements. Keep in mind that `$refs` are **not reactive** unlike `data` properties.

See also the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) to `$refs` with child component instances and the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to the `ref=""` attribute.